# I faced this Compile time error in C# on Main method: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using System;

namespace Calculator {
  class Program {
    public static void Addition(int a, int b) {
      int result = a + b;
      System.Console.WriteLine("Addition result is {0}", result);
    }
    public static void Subtraction(int a, int b) {
      int result = a - b;
      System.Console.WriteLine("Subtraction result is {0}", result);
    }
    public static void Multiplication(int a, int b) {
      int result = a * b;
      System.Console.WriteLine("Multiplication result is {0}", result);
    }
    public static void Division(int a, int b) {
      int result = a / b;
      Console.WriteLine("Division result is {0}", result);
    }
  }
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number ");
    int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Second number ");
    int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter operation symbols +, -, *, /");
    string op = Console.ReadLine();

    if (op.Equals("+")) {
      Program.Addition(num1, num2);
    } else if (op.Equals("-")) {
      Program.Subtraction(num1, num2);
    } else if (op.Equals("*")) {
      Program.Multiplication(num1, num2);
    } else if (op.Equals("/")) {
      Program.Division(num1, num2);
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine("Operation symbol is invalid");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: _A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods_: This isn't a suggestion, it's telling you what you need to fix. If you format your code better by using spaces and newlines (ie: spaces between lines and sections of code), you may find the issue.

Comment: Your `Main` method needs to be contained within the class `Program` (which is easy to see when the code is properly formatted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move one curly brace between the Division and Main methods to the end of the file.
The code will look like this (I formatted it to look better):

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Addition(int a, int b)
        {
            int result = a + b;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Addition result is {0}", result);
        }

        public static void Subtraction(int a, int b)
        {
            int result = a - b;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Subtraction result is {0}", result);
        }

        public static void Multiplication(int a, int b)
        {
            int result = a * b;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Multiplication result is {0}", result);
        }

        public static void Division(int a, int b)
        {
            int result = a / b;
            Console.WriteLine("Division result is {0}", result);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first number ");
            int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Second number ");
            int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter operation symbols +, -, *, /");
            string op= Console.ReadLine();

            if (op.Equals("+"))
            {
                Program.Addition(num1, num2);
            }
            else if (op.Equals("-"))
            {
                Program.Subtraction(num1, num2);
            }
            else if (op.Equals("*"))
            {
                Program.Multiplication(num1, num2);
            }
            else if (op.Equals("/"))
            {
                Program.Division(num1, num2);
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation symbol is invalid");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs because you accidentally end the Program class and the Main method is outside the class, which is not allowed in the C# programming language